# Event / Info about file in printer queue

Tags: powershell, printer

So the question i have is:

Lets say i have a file which is about to get sent to a printer. Is there a event which can tell me where the file which is about to get printed is located? (Like Powershell e.g.)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what stage in the process. For instance, there is the spool director which contains the spooled document. But from that, I do not believe there is a way to say the filepath of the document(eg c:\users\me\documents\word.docx).